# Office.addin.hide APIis not working for Excel and powerpoint Add-ins

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I have followed the article .
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/show-hide-add-in

When calling API Office.addin.hide() it gives below exception for Excel and PowerPoint .

```
RichApi.Error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: The API is only applies to Addin using Shared Runtime.
```

Comment: Error is pretty clear... https://lmgtfy.app/?q=The+API+is+only+applies+to+Addin+using+Shared+Runtime. -1 for me for doing zero research

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use a shared runtime. See [Shared runtime requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/common/shared-runtime-requirement-sets?view=excel-js-preview) to be sure your host application supports it.

Steps required for configuring a shared runtime for Office add-ins are described in the [Configure your Office Add-in to use a shared runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime) article.

You can configure your Office Add-in to run all of its code in a single shared runtime. This enables better coordination across your add-in and access to the DOM and CORS from all parts of your add-in. It also enables additional features such as running code when the document opens, or enabling or disabling ribbon buttons.

Comment: I had tried same but still getting same error . 

<Hosts>
    <Host Name="Workbook" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
   <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="IdentityAPI"  MinVersion="1.1"  />
      <Set Name="SharedRuntime" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <DefaultSettings>

Comment: The `<Runtimes>` section must be entered after the `<Host>` element in the exact order shown in the XML described in the article I mentioned.